# OWIN module invocation on each HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, owin, .net-core

I am new to custom OWIN development let alone writing it in .NET Core. I started writing an OWIN module and I am able to hook it up in the Configure method in the Startup class. It works but it only executes the first time the application starts. I'd like this OWIN middleware to be called on each HTTP request.

Is this possible in .NET Core? It seems in .NET Framework 4.5 we can use "StageMarkers" (app.UseStageMarkers). It doesn't seem like this is an option in .NET Core.

Here is my implementation in startup:

```
app.UseMiddleware<SiteThemerMiddleware>();
```

This is my SiteThemerMiddleware (nothing really done yet to it):

```
public class SiteThemerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SiteThemerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
        //_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SiteThemerMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        //_logger.LogInformation("Handling request: " + context.Request.Path);
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        //_logger.LogInformation("Finished handling request.");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should use UseOwin? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin

Comment: I saw that and I was thinking the samething but UseOwin is not a valid extension method for me. I am using .NetCoreApp 1.0

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core's pipeline is similar to but not directly OWIN (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin for more details). Previously, katana was ASP.NET's implementation of OWIN on top of various hosts including System.Web.

> Is this possible in .NET Core? It seems in .NET Framework 4.5 we can use "StageMarkers" (app.UseStageMarkers). It doesn't seem like this is an option in .NET CORE

UseStageMarkers has nothing to do with running middleware on each request. It was about interleaving middleware throughout various stages within the IIS Integrated pipeline on System.Web.

If you want to run logic on each request, then just write code in the Invoke method in your middleware. That is invoked per request.